# NSButton without "click highlighting"

Tags: highlighting, nsbutton

I've got an `NSButton` with an image (and no text), over a blueish background.
The Style is "`Square`", type is "`Momentary Push In`", not bordered etc.

When I click the button, there is a light rect around it, which is highlighted for a second. How do I get rid of it?

I only want to have the image displayed and when clicked there shouldn't be any highlight indication… Should I subclass the button or is there a simple setting in Interface Builder?

Not clicked – normal state: [image: NSButton normal state]

Clicked - highlighted: [image: highlighted NSButton when clicked]

so I don't want that highlighting rect ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the cell's highlightsBy property.  See [Borderless NSButton turns gray when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797640/borderless-nsbutton-turns-gray-when-clicked) for some more info.