# How NOT to change the background when NSButton clicked

Tags: macos, mouseevent, nsbutton

I have a NSButton on a view I subclass the NSView and draw something in the `drawRect:`, and the view is belong to a NSWindow which

Then when I click the button, I find the view become transparent, which I guess is because the button click changes the button's background. So I subclass the NSButton, 
 
`- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {`

```
[self.window.contentView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
[super mouseDown:theEvent];
[self.window.contentView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

}

Right now when I mouseDown and mouseUp, the view seems right, except there is a flash transparent when I click, even more, when I mouseDown and move out of the button, the background becomes transparent again.

Can anyone tell me what should I do to make the background of a clicked button do not change?
or where to put the redraw code.

THANKS!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797640/borderless-nsbutton-turns-gray-when-clicked

Comment: @ErikGodard Yes, I found that question before, and this does not help. My button is push style and Momentary Push In type, and I do not want change the style and type