# Change NSButton's background color on highlight

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I have an NSButton which I want to have a different background color when it's highlighted than when it's not (transparent on not highlighted, if that makes any difference).

At present, I have the following code

```
[view setWantsLayer:YES];

NSButton* button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[button setBordered:FALSE];
[(NSButtonCell*)[button cell] setHighlightsBy:NSChangeBackgroundCellMask];

[view addSubview:button];
```

This will change the background to the default window background color on click. If I remove `NSChangeBackgroundCellMask` the background goes away.

Is there an easy way I can have a different color for the background, or does this require me to subclass NSButton?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797640/borderless-nsbutton-turns-gray-when-clicked

Answer (score 11):

In the end, I solved it by subclassing `NSButtonCell` and overwriting

```
- (void) highlight:(BOOL)flag withFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView*)controlView
```

to make the changes I wanted (changing `controlView.layer.backgroundColor` based on `flag`)

Comment: I'm not seeing this method on the class reference docs for `NSButtonCell`? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSButtonCell_Class/

Comment: @AdamJohns It's documented in the [`NSCell` superclass](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/highlight:withFrame:inView:)

Comment: This is correct but be careful! In Mojave, if you overwrite any draw methods, this will not work!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to subclass your `NSButton` and override its `mouseDown:` and `mouseUp:` events, change the color of your `NSButton` in these events.

Comment: Oddly enough, mouseUp: wasn't getting called properly for me so I ended up subclassing NSButtonCell instead.

Comment: Please note: Mouse events of the NSButtonCell are only getting called when you set showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = YES

Comment: mouseUp never called for me

Comment: NSButton enters its own nested event loop on mouseDown:. That's why you're not getting a mouseUp: event. The nested event loop for tracking the mouse swallows it to know when to return to the main event loop.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of Cobbal's answer:

```
override func highlight(_ flag: Bool, withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        //do nothing, to disable highlight
}
```