# Remove ugly grey from NSButton when using image and text

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

In interface builder I have an image button with the text set to "Save"

Here is a screenshot of how it looks when the app is run. The button on the right is one without text so you can see what it should look like. As you can see with text it looks bad as the App is throwing in that ugly grey color on it's own.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/12838984/1305067

Comment: It's a different issue.

Comment: You need to set your button style as a `Rounded Rect`...

Comment: rounded rect did not change it

Comment: Can you show us what properties are set on the NSButton?